# How to make telegram bot multiuserable? Meaning that multiple users could use the bot simultaneously. #python #aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, aiogram

I have developed a telegram bot on Python using Aiogram 2.3 that offers user to play "Truth or Dare" game. Bot works pretty good with one user, but when 2+ users start using bot in the same time, global variables, states, localisation becomes a mess, because it works like there is only one instance. And that is true, because I have created only one 'bot' instance, that is used to work in all handlers.

I expect that that OOP will solve the problem, but currently is quiet confused with the exact solution. I did't manage to find suitable code in the internet, so I wanted to ask if you can guide me to some already invented solution on this matter or show me how can I solve that.

The bot is launched from **app.py**. Here is the code of it:

```py
from aiogram import executor

from loader import dp

import handlers

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Here is **loader.py**:

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from mainUnit.config import API_TOKEN


bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
```

If you need any additional code, I will be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database to store and retrieve user data. Use Telegram user_id as an identifier. Each time a new message arrives find user data with its user id and retrieve other data related to the user.
I recommend using the sqlite3 database as soon as it is best to fit for small, lightweight, serverless projects.